# iPad 2 Build Succeeded -> nothing happens

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad

I have a problem with my iPad 2, if I build a project it shows that build succeeded, but nothing happens on the iPad. Console is empty. 
However, I can run my project on Simulator(iPhone/iPad) as well as on my iPhone 4S...

Comment: Also try rebooting the Mac.True story...

Comment: I have the same issue for my iPod touch (ios3.1) if i want to deploy my app that runs fine on iphone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have figured it out, the problem was in the info.plist file, other developer has entered there "Required device capabilities"-> camera-flash, auto focus camera ;)

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks for posting back the fix.  This is bound to help someone else.

Answer (score 1):

XCode->Window->Organizer->Your iPad (on left)

Make sure it's "Configured for Development". Also make sure it's provisioned, and that the provisioning profiles are installed (this is probably ok but I thought I'd mention it). Otherwise, restart programs/iPad/iTunes, reconnect, sync, try again.

If still no luck, let us know.

Answer (score 1):

First steps - Clean the project and restart X-Code.
Next try rebooting the iPad (it sounds like the OS is never getting a handle on the process.

Finally put an NSLog statement in the applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions method in the appDelegate.